# PHP Session not passing multiple post form data through multiple pages

Tags: php, forms, session

I am trying to take form input from the user and pass that information to another page with another form then take input again and pass that plus the previous data to another page that will display the input from both forms.

On the first page, the user will enter information, click submit, and open the second page which will display their input from the first page and ask them to enter more information. They will enter information on the second page and click submit again which will bring them to a third page displaying all their input from the previous pages.

When I run my code, it does not carry the post values from the form to the next page.

I know there are multiple questions about issues such as this, but all of the answers I have looked over and tried did not fix my problem.

Here is my code:

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'session id: ';
echo session_id();
$_SESSION['test1'] = $_POST['test1'];
?>

<html>
<body>
    <p>Page 1 Form</p>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="test1"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'page2.php<br />';
echo 'session id: ';
echo session_id();
echo '<br />';
echo 'input from page1.php: ';
echo $_SESSION['test1'];
$_SESSION['test2'] = $_POST['test2'];
?>

<html>
<body>
    <p>Page 2 Form</p>
        <form action="page3.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="test2"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit!" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'page3.php<br />'
echo 'session id: ';
echo session_id();
echo '<br />';
echo $_SESSION['test1'];
echo $_SESSION['test2'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['test1']` is never read because `page1.php` submits to `page2.php` and `page2.php` reads `test2`.

Also you don't need to use the session if you're just POSTing data along. You can do this:

page1.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Page 1 Form</p>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="test1"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Page 2 Form</p>
        <form action="page3.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="test1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["test1"]);?>"/>
            <input type="text" name="test2"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit!" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page3.php

```
<?php
echo 'page3.php<br />'
var_dump($_POST["test1"]);
var_dump($_POST["test2"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should field the value after value is parsing.
i think u have an empty session is because,

```
1. $_SESSION['test1'] = $_POST['test1'];
```

but your action going to "page2.php", and you field the session before form is submit so you get an empty value, the better way is you should field $_SESSION['test1'] on page2.php

```
2. $_SESSION['test2'] = $_POST['test2'];
```

your action going to "page3.php", you should field $_SESSION['test2'] on page3.php

*so, the complete code should look like this.*

**pages 1**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'session id: ';
echo session_id();
?>

<html>
<body>
    <p>Page 1 Form</p>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="test1"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**pages 2**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'page2.php<br />';
echo 'session id: ';
echo session_id();
echo '<br />';
echo 'input from page1.php: '.$_POST['test1'];
$_SESSION['test1'] = $_POST['test1'];
?>

<html>
<body>
    <p>Page 2 Form</p>
        <form action="page3.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="test2"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit!" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**pages 3**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'page3.php<br />'
echo 'session id: ';
echo session_id();
echo '<br />';
$_SESSION['test2'] = $_POST['test2'];
echo $_SESSION['test1'];
echo $_SESSION['test2'];
?>
```